# std::stringstream - discard a value

Tags: c++, stream

Sometimes I use std::stringstream to parse a text file, e.g.

```
8 9
100 1002 3.345
100 102  2.345


std::stringstream ss(file);
int unused1, unused2, first_useful_value;
ss >> unused1 >> unused2;
ss >> first_useful_value >> ...
```

now suppose that the first line, i.e.

```
8 9
```

are useless values to me and I just need to discard them. I might consider the entire line useless **or** I might consider **some** of those values useless.

My question is: is there any way to discard a value of a given type without having to declare useless variables on the stack (either wasteful and less readable)?

Comment: You only need one "dummy" `int` to consume the unused values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::stringstream::ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) with delimeter `\n` to skip the first line as follows:

```
  ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/661880d248543550)

or use as delimiter space or what ever separates your values to discard one at a time:

```
ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' '); // delimiter is space
ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ','); // delimeter is comma
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c160626da29ca4f)

Comment: Or use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead of the magic number `256`.

Comment: Not terribly readable but definitely the correct solution. Thanks.